# IF using inner join MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

How do I build a joint to select either table

**Table jobs**

```
Id    |    name    |   salary   |   company   |  type
1     |    php     |   17.850   |   5         |  1
2     |    mysql   |   4.500    |   89        |  2
2     |    nodejs  |   7.500    |   89        |  1
```

**Table Company**

```
Id    |    name    |   Area     |   status   
1     |    Facebook|   Developer|   1
2     |    Google  |   Manager  |   1
```

**Table Candidate**

```
Id    |    name         |   City     |   phone   
1     |    Alan Kout    |   Nevada   |   1 555 6666
2     |    Wagner Mom   |   L.A.     |   1 444 8965
```

*My query mysql, inner join candidate or company*

If `type == 1` in table jobs `INNER JOIN ON table company`

If `type == 2` in table jobs `INNER JOIN ON table candidate`

*Example*

```
SELECT * FROM table_jobs
IF(table_jobs.type == 1, INNER JOIN table_company, INNER JOIN table_candidate)
```

This is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  table_jobs tj
    LEFT JOIN table_company tco ON tj.type = 1 AND tco.id = tj.id
    LEFT JOIN table_candidate tca ON tj.type = 2 AND tca.id = tj.id
```

This will join to `table_company` where the type is 1, and `table_candidate` where the type is 2.

You can then `SELECT` whichever columns are needed from each table as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Use `left join` and `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT tj.*,
       coalesce(co.name, ca.name) as name,
       . . . 
FROM table_jobs tj LEFT JOIN
     table_company co
     ON co.id = tj.id and tj.type = 1 LEFT JOIN
     table_candidate ca
     ON ca.id = tj.id and tj.type = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want both joins in one result you can use the `UNION` operator

```
SELECT *
FROM table_jobs INNER JOIN table_company
WHERE table_jobs.type=1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM table_jobs INNER JOIN table_candidate
WHERE table_jobs.type=2
```

Comment: `table_candidate` and `table_company` have different data types and data. This union will throw an error.

Comment: depends on how the columns are actually defined